# How sort with script sort in Elasticsearch on different field has different type?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nosql, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I have a nested field my index, value, numberValue, and type are some of its properties

```
"metadata": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
             "numbervalue": {
                "type": "double"
              },
             "type": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }...

            }
```

I want to sort on *value* if the type is *STRING* and sort on *numberValue* if the type is *NUMBER*. I read some examples about script sort we can choose a field with script but in all of them, *type* was fixed. is it possible to have conditional type in script sort?

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: actually the main query is not important the I want to change the sort part in `query : "sort" : [
    {
      "metadata.value" : {
        "order" : "asc",
        "unmapped_type" : "long",
        "nested_filter" : {
          "term" : {
            "metadata.path" : {
              "value" : "age",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        "nested_path" : "metadata"
      }
    }
  ],`